Is von Neumann entropy symmetric?
In a multiparty system, Shannon entropy is symmetric with respect to exchange of two parties. Is this also true for von Neumann entropy in case of a multiparty density matrix? If yes, is there any formal proof?

Can you put some equations? It is hard to understand what exactly you mean. In the case of identical fermions or bosons, the density operator must be invariant under exchange symmetry, so $P\rhoP^\dagger=\rho$ anyways. So I suppose you consider distinguishable particles?

Symmetry of von Neumann entropy: is $S(\rho_{ABC}) = S(\rho_{BAC})$ for an arbitrary three-party density matrix $\rho_{ABC}$ under exchange of parties A and B?

@asu oh, it looks from your comment like you're asking a rather different question to the one I was answering. I was talking about the von Neumann entropies of the single-party reduced states (which is commonly used as an entanglement measure). The global von Neumann entropy is invariant under any unitary operation - $S(U\rho U^\dagger) = S(\rho)$, including swapping around subsystems as a special case.

@asu Please add formulas to the question. It is unclear what you are asking. For what you write in the comment, the entropy is by definition for the whole system, regardless how you order the parties (this has no meaning and is just a formal choice).

Let $\mathcal H_A,\mathcal H_B$ and $\mathcal H_C$ be three Hilbert spaces and write $\mathcal H_{ABC} = \mathcal H_A\otimes \mathcal H_B \otimes\mathcal H_C$ (and likewise define $\mathcal H_{BAC}$).
The exchange operator $P :  \to \mathcal H_B\otimes \mathcal H_A \otimes\mathcal H_C$ (which sends $|\psi\rangle_A|\phi\rangle_B|\rho\rangle_C$ to $|\phi\rangle_B|\psi\rangle_A|\rho\rangle_C$) is unitary. We can check that by checking that  it preserves the scalar product. (If we have fermionic states, we might want to include a minus sign when both $|\psi\rangle_A$ and $|\phi\rangle_B$ are fermionic, but this still results in a unitary operator.)
If $\rho_{ABC}$ is a density matrix on $\mathcal H_{ABC}$, then the corresponding density matrix on $\mathcal H_{BAC}$ is $\rho_{BAC} = P\rho_{ABC} P^\dagger$. We can then compute :
\begin{align}
S(\rho_{BAC}) &= \operatorname{Tr}(\rho_{BAC}\log(\rho_{BAC})) \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}(P (\rho_{ABC}\log(\rho_{ABC})) P^{\dagger}) \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}( (\rho_{ABC}\log(\rho_{ABC})) P^{\dagger}P) \\
&=\operatorname{Tr}( \rho_{ABC}\log(\rho_{ABC})) \\
&= S(\rho_{ABC})
\end{align}
Of course there is nothing special about having $3$ parties, this work equally well if the Hilbert space is the tensor product of $n$ spaces for any positive integer $n$.

For bipartite pure states the answer is yes, directly from the Schmidt decomposition. We decompose
\begin{align}
|\psi\rangle &= \sum_j \alpha_j |a_j\rangle|b_j\rangle,
\end{align}
then the spectrum of the reduced state on either subsystem has the same non-zero elements (the squares of the real numbers $\alpha_j$). From this it follows that the con Neumann entropies are the same.
On the other hand in essentially any case except for bipartite pure states the answer is no. Consider the tripartite state
\begin{align}
    |\phi\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle|0\rangle +|1\rangle|1\rangle )|0\rangle,
\end{align}
clearly theres no reason to expect any symmetry when we swap (e.g.) parties 2 and 3.

Can we write a tripartite pure state in the manner you have written? No mention of parties and their dimensions.

@ors Could you compute von Neumann entropies for some tripartite system and show that they are indeed different ?

@SolubleFish If you compute the single party reduced states of the tripartite state $\phi$ in my answer you'll see the reduced states of the first two parties are both maximally mixed, while the reduced state of the third party is pure.

@asu There are some generalisations people have tried to make to bring the Schmidt decomposition to three and more party systems, but they don't really work so well. In general the answer is no, you can't write a tripartite state in the form of a Schmidt decompostion.

In the comments below OP, he explains that his question is whether $S(\rho_{ABC}) = S(\rho_{BAC})$. No mentions is made of reduced states.
